# Regex match and grouping

Tags: regex

Here's a sample string which I want do a regex on

```
101-nocola_conte_-_fuoco_fatuo_(koop_remix)
```

The first digit in "101" is the disc number and the next 2 digits are the track numbers. How do I match the track numbers and ignore the disc number (first digit)?

Comment: Next time, try to be a bit more precise in specifying your environement like language, OS and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you don't mind what the disk number is, but you want to match, say, track number 01 ?

In perl you would match it like so: "^[0-9]01.*"
or more simply "^.01.*" - which means that you don't even mind if the first char is not a digit.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
/^\d(\d\d)/
```

Would match one digit at the start of the string, then capture the following two digits

Comment: +1 to ^\d(\d\d) : the ending and trailing / are not part of the regex.. but rather a regex delimiter in ruby for example.

Comment: Showing your delimter also helps to indicate what chars you may or may not have escaped

Comment: just trying to protect the OP if he was on a MS/.net language.. no righteous indignation intended :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d(\d\d)
```

You may need `\` in front of the `(` depending on which environment you intend to run the regex into (like `vi(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Which programming language? For the shell something with egrep will do the job:

```
echo '101-nocola_conte_-_fuoco_fatuo_(koop_remix)' | egrep -o '^[0-9]{3}' | egrep -o '[0-9]{2}$'
```