# Regex Group in Perl: how to capture elements into array from regex group that matches unknown number of/multiple/variable occurrences from a string?

Tags: regex, perl, grouping, match

In Perl, how can I use one regex grouping to capture more than one occurrence that matches it, into several array elements?

For example, for a string:

```
var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var3=hello
```

to process this with code:

```
$string = "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";

my @array = $string =~ <regular expression here>

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar( @array ); $i++ )
{
  print $i.": ".$array[$i]."\n";
}
```

I would like to see as output:

```
0: var1=100
1: var2=90
2: var5=hello
3: var3="a, b, c"
4: var7=test
5: var3=hello
```

What would I use as a regex?

The commonality between things I want to match here is an assignment string pattern, so something like:

```
my @array = $string =~ m/(\w+=[\w\"\,\s]+)*/;
```

Where the * indicates one or more occurrences matching the group.

(I discounted using a split() as some matches contain spaces within themselves (i.e. var3...) and would therefore not give desired results.)

With the above regex, I only get:

```
0: var1=100 var2
```

Is it possible in a regex? Or addition code required?

Looked at existing answers already, when searching for "perl regex multiple group" but not enough clues:

- [Dealing with multiple capture groups in multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159991/dealing-with-multiple-capture-groups-in-multiple-records)
- [Multiple matches within a regex group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313332/multiple-matches-within-a-regex-group)
- [Regex: Repeated capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172643/regex-repeated-capturing-groups)
- [Regex match and grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446126/regex-match-and-grouping)
- [How do I regex match with grouping with unknown number of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407435/how-do-i-regex-match-with-grouping-with-unknown-number-of-groups)
- [awk extract multiple groups from each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116193/awk-extract-multiple-groups-from-each-line)
- [Matching multiple regex groups and removing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791097/matching-multiple-regex-groups-and-removing-them)
- [Perl: Deleting multiple reccuring lines where a certain criterion is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685456/perl-deleting-multiple-re-occuring-lines-where-a-certain-criteria-is-met)
- [Regex matching into multiple groups per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398730/regex-matching-into-multiple-groups-per-line)
- [PHP RegEx Grouping Multiple Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087720/php-regex-grouping-multiple-matches)
- [How to find multiple occurrences with regex groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246237/how-to-find-multiple-occurances-with-regex-groups)

Comment: TLDR, but +1 for doing your homework diligently.

Comment: BTW, I think that your problem is NOT multiple groups but the matching quotes. Which CAN be handled in Perl RegEx but very very carefully

Comment: http://ideone.com/Qvm2u

Comment: @Alan: That is a great regex!

Comment: @Alan: works for me too! How very modest of you to post it as a comment rather than an answer though. I might have accepted as the answer if it was posted as an answer! Thank you very much though. Your answer is probably the most simplest (i.e. neatest solution) i.e. - which doesn't require supporting code e.g. a looping construct.

Comment: P.S. I've not heard of ideone.com before, so @Alan, thanks for introducing me to this as well as your solution.

Comment: Having filled in the gaps in your code, I still wasn't sure what part of it your question was about.  Being a bit rushed as well, I just posted the link and bailed.  Was it the way all the matches are accumulated in the array that you were trying to understand?

Comment: Yes it was. But also to be able to treat 'internal' spaces i.e. bound by a pair of " as part of a matching pattern and not as a separator i.e. 'external' space that resides between matching patterns. Yours and other solutions do this. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 just another upvote (to your last comment, can't upvote you twice on your solution comment) to show appreciation for your answer. Yours is probably the most simplest of pure regex solutions here.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
my $string = "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";

while($string =~ /(?:^|\s+)(\S+)\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|\S*)/g) {
        print "<$1> => <$2>\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
<var1> => <100>
<var2> => <90>
<var5> => <hello>
<var3> => <"a, b, c">
<var7> => <test>
<var3> => <hello>
```

Explanation:

Last piece first: the `g` flag at the end means that you can apply the regex to the string multiple times. The second time it will continue matching where the last match ended in the string.

Now for the regex: `(?:^|\s+)` matches either the beginning of the string or a group of one or more spaces. This is needed so when the regex is applied next time, we will skip the spaces between the key/value pairs. The `?:` means that the parentheses content won't be captured as group (we don't need the spaces, only key and value). `\S+` matches the variable name. Then we skip any amount of spaces and an equal sign in between. Finally, `("[^"]*"|\S*)/` matches either two quotes with any amount of characters in between, or any amount of non-space characters for the value. Note that the quote matching is pretty fragile and won't handle escpaped quotes properly, e.g. `"\"quoted\""` would result in `"\"`.

EDIT:

Since you really want to get the whole assignment, and not the single keys/values, here's a one-liner that extracts those:

```
my @list = $string =~ /(?:^|\s+)((?:\S+)\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|\S*))/g;
```

Comment: The OP said one regex group was desired, and this captures into 2 regex groups...

Comment: Right, my fault. You can fix this be adding more parens around the key/value part of the regex.

Comment: So you could do: http://ideone.com/7EQgz :-

my $string = "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";
 
my @array = ();
while($string =~ /(?:^|\s+)(\S+)\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|\S*)/g)
{
  push( @array, $1."=".$2 );
  my @array = ();
}
 
for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar( @array ); $i++ )
{
     print $i.": ".$array[$i]."\n";
}

Comment: Or, http://ideone.com/otgyc   -- which puts an extra set of brackets around the whole expression:

my $string = "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";
 
while($string =~ /((?:^|\s+)(\S+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"|\S*))/g) {
        print "<$1>\n";
}

Comment: +1 to your answer as it does work. I'll have a look at all the other answers and come back soon to select an accepted answer. Thanks very much for your input and for explaining the regex too!

Comment: In your second comment, I'd not include the leading `(?:^|\s+)` in the surrounding parens, as you're probably not interested in the spaces. Try this:

while($string =~ /(?:^|\s+)((\S+)\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|\S*))/g) {
        push @list, $1;
}

Comment: Updated the post with a one-liner that extracts the complete var=value assignments.

Comment: +1 for the update, and for it being a one-liner and not requiring supporting code. Thankyou. On further thoughts, splitting them as var, value pairs actually suits my requirement - you read my mind there. But a regex to find the combined pattern is instructive - perhaps if I want to apply the solution to other kinds of patterns for future problems (that I don't know about yet) - so your update facilitates this.

Comment: Accepted answer. Thank you very much to everyone else - for every other solution that works I've, at least, +1 to your answer and probably +1 your comments. I've accepted @jkramer's answer because it is a pure regex solution (the oneliner at least) - the original requirement. Being a pure regex means it could likely be used in other regex capable languages as well, it's portable. Being a regex means it is transparent and has a fine level of granularity of extensibility/adjustment. @jkramer also explained their answer. But for the others - don't take this as a criticism at all...

Comment: ...as everyone else provided some really excellent answers too - broadening my horizons & knowledge about how it could be done - particularly instead of purely using regex's: modules & routines. Also the approaches such as parsing. So, thank you to everyone. Many answers make this a rich & broad response to the problem. @jkramer was 1 of first to reply & has got many votes, so following crowd wisdom as well. But I realise everyone has busy schedules so again this is no criticism about replying early. A late, considered, response is very valuable too, as @Sinan Ünür and @gbacon demonstrate.

Comment: Credit to @Alan Moore too for providing an answer as a comment and for introducing ideone.com!

Comment: Why is it `while` and not `for` or `foreach` ? It looks strange coming from other languages

Answer (score 11):

With regular expressions, use a technique that I like to call tack-and-stretch: anchor on features you know will be there (tack) and then grab what's between (stretch).

In this case, you know that a single assignment matches

```
\b\w+=.+
```

and you have many of these repeated in `$string`. Remember that `\b` means word boundary:

> A word boundary (`\b`) is a spot between two characters that has a `\w` on one side of it and a `\W` on the other side of it (in either order), counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the string as matching a `\W`.

The values in the assignments can be a little tricky to describe with a regular expression, but you also know that each value will terminate with whitespace—although not necessarily the first whitespace encountered!—followed by either another assignment or end-of-string.

To avoid repeating the assertion pattern, compile it once with [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and reuse it in your pattern along with a [look-ahead assertion `(?=...)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) to stretch the match just far enough to capture the entire value while also preventing it from spilling into the next variable name.

Matching against your pattern in list context with `m//g` gives the following behavior:

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching—that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.

The pattern `$assignment` uses non-greedy `.+?` to cut off the value as soon as the look-ahead sees another assignment or end-of-line. Remember that the match returns the substrings from *all* capturing subpatterns, so the look-ahead's alternation uses non-capturing `(?:...)`. The `qr//`, in contrast, contains implicit capturing parentheses.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = <<'EOF';
var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var3=hello
EOF

my $assignment = qr/\b\w+ = .+?/x;
my @array = $string =~ /$assignment (?= \s+ (?: $ | $assignment))/gx;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar( @array ); $i++ )
{
  print $i.": ".$array[$i]."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0: var1=100
1: var2=90
2: var5=hello
3: var3="a, b, c"
4: var7=test
5: var3=hello
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Tried your solution, it works for me too -thanks! +1. Also thanks for suggesting your systematic approach/technique to regex building: "tack-and-stretch: anchor on features you know will be there (tack) and then grab what's between (stretch)." I'll read your answer more deeply when I've more time and feedback later.

Comment: @Rob I'm glad it helps. Enjoy!

Comment: +1 That is a really great explanation of how you approached this problem.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not saying this is what you *should* do, but what you're trying to do is write a **Grammar**. Now your example is *very* simple for a Grammar, but [Damian Conway](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/)'s module [Regexp::Grammars](http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars) is *really* great at this. If you have to grow this at all, you'll find it will make your life much easier. I use it quite a bit here - it is kind of  perl6-ish.

```
use Regexp::Grammars;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $parser = qr{
    <[pair]>+
    <rule: pair>     <key>=(?:"<list>"|<value=literal>)
    <token: key>     var\d+
    <rule: list>     <[MATCH=literal]> ** (,)
    <token: literal> \S+

}xms;

q[var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var3=hello] =~ $parser;
die Dumper {%/};
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var3=hello',
          'pair' => [
                      {
                        '' => 'var1=100',
                        'value' => '100',
                        'key' => 'var1'
                      },
                      {
                        '' => 'var2=90',
                        'value' => '90',
                        'key' => 'var2'
                      },
                      {
                        '' => 'var5=hello',
                        'value' => 'hello',
                        'key' => 'var5'
                      },
                      {
                        '' => 'var3="a, b, c"',
                        'key' => 'var3',
                        'list' => [
                                    'a',
                                    'b',
                                    'c'
                                  ]
                      },
                      {
                        '' => 'var7=test',
                        'value' => 'test',
                        'key' => 'var7'
                      },
                      {
                        '' => 'var3=hello',
                        'value' => 'hello',
                        'key' => 'var3'
                      }
                    ]
```

Comment: +1 because I like the idea of the grammar concept (having studied them to an extent in Computer Science) though I haven't tried this answer. I like the grammar concept because this approach could be applied to solve even more complex problems, particularly in parsing code/data from a legacy obsolete language, for migration into a new language or data driven system/database -- which was actually the reason my original question (though I didn't mention it at the time.)

Comment: I'd welcome you you to check out this module. Too often Regexs blur into Grammar -- and if you're going to write a Grammar with a Regex (not a bad idea) then this module is really dead on. Check out [my application of it to parse the `COPY` command in my psql shell](http://github.com/EvanCarroll/pgperlshell/blob/master/bdshell).

Answer (score 5):

A bit over the top maybe, but an excuse for me to look into http://p3rl.org/Parse::RecDescent. How about making a parser?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::RecDescent;

use Regexp::Common;

my $grammar = <<'_EOGRAMMAR_'
INTEGER: /[-+]?\d+/
STRING: /\S+/
QSTRING: /$Regexp::Common::RE{quoted}/

VARIABLE: /var\d+/
VALUE: ( QSTRING | STRING | INTEGER )

assignment: VARIABLE "=" VALUE /[\s]*/ { print "$item{VARIABLE} => $item{VALUE}\n"; }

startrule: assignment(s)
_EOGRAMMAR_
;

$Parse::RecDescent::skip = '';
my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new($grammar);

my $code = q{var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var8=" haha \" heh " var3=hello};
$parser->startrule($code);
```

yields:

```
var1 => 100
var2 => 90
var5 => hello
var3 => "a, b, c"
var7 => test
var8 => " haha \" heh "
var3 => hello
```

PS. Note the double var3, if you want the latter assignment to overwrite the first one you can use a hash to store the values, and then use them later.

PPS. My first thought was to split on '=' but that would fail if a string contained '=' and since regexps are almost always bad for parsing, well I ended up trying it out and it works.

Edit: Added support for escaped quotes inside quoted strings.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll need to install Parse module on my particular system to try it out though. I would therefore favour a solution without this dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had to parse x509 certificates "Subject" lines. They had similar form to the one you have provided:

```
echo 'Subject: C=HU, L=Budapest, O=Microsec Ltd., CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA 2009/emailAddress=info@e-szigno.hu' | \
  perl -wne 'my @a = m/(\w+\=.+?)(?=(?:, \w+\=|$))/g; print "$_\n" foreach @a;'

C=HU
L=Budapest
O=Microsec Ltd.
CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA 2009/emailAddress=info@e-szigno.hu
```

Short description of the regex:

`(\w+\=.+?)` - capture words followed by '=' and any subsequent symbols in non greedy mode
`(?=(?:, \w+\=|$))` - which are followed by either another `, KEY=val`  or end of line.

The interesting part of the regex used are:

- `.+?` - Non greedy mode
- `(?:pattern)` - Non capturing mode
- `(?=pattern)` zero-width positive look-ahead assertion

Answer (score 2):

This one will provide you also common escaping in double-quotes as for example var3="a, \"b, c".

```
@a = /(\w+=(?:\w+|"(?:[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)*"))/g;
```

In action:

```
echo 'var1=100 var2=90 var42="foo\"bar\\" var5=hello var3="a, b, c" var7=test var3=hello' |
perl -nle '@a = /(\w+=(?:\w+|"(?:[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)*"))/g; $,=","; print @a'
var1=100,var2=90,var42="foo\"bar\\",var5=hello,var3="a, b, c",var7=test,var3=hello
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;
use YAML;

my $string =
    "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";

my @parts = shellwords $string;
print Dump \@parts;

@parts = map { { split /=/ } } @parts;

print Dump \@parts;
```

Comment: I think this is better done with `Text::ParseWords` rather than `Text::Shellwords`. `Text::ParseWords` has similar functionality but is part of the Perl core.

Comment: @drewk Thanks for the reminder. I always confuse the two. I'll update the example to use `Text::ParseWords`.

Comment: Works fine for me. See output further on in this comment. This depends on a module - I was lucky on my machine that this is present but for some Perl modules this is not always guaranteed on every distribution/platform. Here's the output: ---
- var1=100
- var2=90
- var5=hello
- 'var3=a, b, c'
- var7=test
- var3=hello
---
- var1: 100
- var2: 90
- var5: hello
- var3: 'a, b, c'
- var7: test
- var3: hello

Comment: @Rob: I think that `Text::ParseWords` has been part of the core distribution since 5.00. The shellwords functionality is very useful and prior to 5.00 many used a shell eval to get that even with the security isk. Don't need to do that anymore since 5.00.

Comment: @Rob: Ask yourself which one is more maintainable: A complicated patter, a custom parser or a core module dependency.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Thank you. Should have given it earlier. Good to know that the module has been in since 5.00 - that is a long time ago. So we should be safe with that.

Comment: +1 re: your last comment about maintainability. Using a pure regex solution does have the advantage in portability across different languages for re-use. Though, yes my question was specifically for Perl. But pure regex answers should help developers in other languages too. In fact my 'homework' searching SO for an existing solution included looking at solutions in other languages to port across, though didn't find any that did exactly what I wanted hence asking the question here.

Comment: @Rob: The source code for `Text::ParseWords` is available. http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHORNY/Text-ParseWords-3.27/ParseWords.pm See the pattern in `parse_line`. Isn't it good that someone else did that once so others can use it many, many, many times?

Comment: I agree - reuse is a good thing. I'll check out the link as I'm very interested in parsers at the moment in general, for other similar problems where I'm migrating legacy code into a cleaner more modern data driven solution. So thank you very much @Sinan Ünür for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a RegEx solution or other code. Here is a (mostly) non regex solution using only core modules. The only regex is `\s+` to determine the delimiter; in this case one or more spaces.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;
my $string="var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";  

my @array = quotewords('\s+', 0, $string);

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar( @array ); $i++ )
{
    print $i.": ".$array[$i]."\n";
}
```

Or you can execute the code [HERE](http://ideone.com/SkQqM)

The output is:

```
0: var1=100
1: var2=90
2: var5=hello
3: var3=a, b, c
4: var7=test
5: var3=hello
```

If you really want a regex solution, Alan Moore's [comment](http://ideone.com/Qvm2u) linking to his code on IDEone is the gas!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with regexes, however it's fragile.

```
my $string = "var1=100 var2=90 var5=hello var3=\"a, b, c\" var7=test var3=hello";

my $regexp = qr/( (?:\w+=[\w\,]+) | (?:\w+=\"[^\"]*\") )/x;
my @matches = $string =~ /$regexp/g;
```

Comment: Might need to add something missing or correct something here, as I get an error message when I run it: http://ideone.com/4bR1b and also on my own machine too.

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at ./regex_solution.pl line 8, near "qr/( (?:\w+=[\w\,]+) | (
syntax error at ./regex_solution.pl line 8, near "qr/( (?:\w+=[\w\,]+) | (?:\w+=\"[^\"]*\") )/xg"
Execution of ./regex_solution.pl aborted due to compilation errors.