# Getting multiple matches within a string using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, multiple-matches

After having read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459721/regex-group-in-perl-how-to-capture-elements-into-array-from-regex-group-that-ma) and having tried my code several times, I keep on getting the same undesired output.

Let's assume the string I'm searching is "I saw wilma yesterday".
The regex should capture **each word** followed by an 'a' and its **optional** 5 following characters or spaces.

The code I wrote is the following:

```
$_ = "I saw wilma yesterday";

if (@m = /(\w+)a(.{5,})?/g){
    print "found " . @m . " matches\n";

    foreach(@m){
        print "\t\"$_\"\n";
    }
}
```

However, I kept on getting the following output:

```
found 2 matches
    "s"
    "w wilma yesterday"
```

while I expected to get the following one:

```
found 3 matches:
    "saw wil"
    "wilma yest"
    "yesterday"
```

until I found out that the return values inside `@m` were `$1` and `$2`, as you can notice.

Now, since the `/g` flag is on, and I don't think the problem is about the regex, how could I get the desired output?

Comment: I don't understand why you have `day` in your expected result and not `yesterday`?

Comment: Well, you're right. Just edited.

Comment: Ok, i have a pattern for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this pattern that allows overlapped results:

```
(?=\b(\w+a.{1,5}))
```

or

```
(?=(?i)\b([a-z]+a.{0,5}))
```

example:

```
use strict;
my $str = "I saw wilma yesterday";
my @matches = ($str =~ /(?=\b([a-z]+a.{0,5}))/gi);
print join("\n", @matches),"\n";
```

more explanations:

You can't have overlapped results with a regex since when a character is "eaten" by the regex engine it can't be eaten a second time. The trick to avoid this constraint, is to use a lookahead (that is a tool that only checks, but not matches) which can run through the string several times, and put a capturing group inside.

For another example of this behaviour, you can try the example code without the word boundary (`\b`) to see the result.

Comment: I tested this and it worked. Well done. `while ( m/(?=\b(\w+a.{1,5}))/g ) { print "$1\n"; }`

Comment: Yeah, It works properly. But wasn't the "?=" the lookhahead option? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @none: the lookahead allows overlapped matches, then you can have overlapped results ( as `saw wil` and `wilma yest`) in one shot. see the example.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you want to capture everything inside the expression, i.e.:

```
/(\w+a(?:.{5,})?)/
```

Next you want to start your search from one character past where the last expression's first character matched.

The `pos()` function allows you to specify where a `/g` regex starts its search from.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = "I saw wilma yesterday";    
while ($s =~ /(\w+a(.{0,5}))/g){
    print "\t\"$1\"\n";
    pos($s) = pos($s) - length($2); 
}
```

Gives you:

```
"saw wil"
"wilma yest"
"yesterday"
```

But I don't know why you should get `day` and not `yesterday`.