# regex select two words and trim everything else

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line like this

```
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.6889.2.69.5.1.58.0 = IpAddress: 10.169.130.48 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.6889.2.69.5.1.52.0 = STRING: "999"
```

and I want select the ip address (10.169.130.48) and the string output (999) and trim everything else and I am using this code.

```
/.*\s=\sIpAddress:\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\sSNMPv2-SMI.*\s=\sSTRING:\s\"(\d+)\"/
```

but I only get 10.169.130.48 not the string out put. my question is I can't use two () to select what I want? what is the other option?

Comment: Using what tool/language for this regex?

Comment: and what code are you using to output the second parameter

Comment: Why do you have a limitation on how many matching groups (parens) you can use? If you are trying to match two distinct patterns within the string, you need two matching groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct, you are just missing the result. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460135/89112) for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine. The only thing is, in Perl you don't need to escape the double quotes characters. Since the forward slash notation is not interpreted as a string.

You can access the second capture through $2

Comment: I agree that the escapes aren't necessary, but does that affect the outcome of the regex? Or is his problem something else?

Answer (score 0):

Following regex works in Javascript:

```
var s = 'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.6889.2.69.5.1.58.0 = IpAddress: 10.169.130.48 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.6889.2.69.5.1.52.0 = STRING: "999"'

var m = s.match(/\bIpAddress:\s*([^\s]+).*?\bSTRING:\s*([^\s]+)/);
// m[1] = 10.169.130.48
// m[2] = "999"
```