# extracting links in regex php

Tags: php, regex

I'm having issues extracting links in regex using `preg_match_all()`.

I have the following string:

```
some random text <a href="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link1.pdf\">Link1</a><a href="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link2.pdf\">Link2</a>
```

I would like to extract the link to the files and the files format into two separate variables.

Any regex gurus here? I've been struggling with this all day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=href=")(.*?\.(.*?))\\
```

Try this.just grab the captures.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/80

```
$data = 'some random text <a href="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link1.pdf\">Link1</a><a href="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link2.pdf\">Link2</a>"';
$regex =  '/(?<=href=")(.*?\.(.*?))\\\\/';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link1.pdf\
            [1] => http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link2.pdf\
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link1.pdf
            [1] => http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Link2.pdf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => pdf
            [1] => pdf
        )

)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. But for some odd reason using this expression in preg_match_all() doesn't work for me.. It returns NULL. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nevos use `groups()`, cpature `group1` for link ,`group2` for format

Comment: What's `groups()`? I can't find reference to it

Comment: @Nevos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459721/regex-group-in-perl-how-to-capture-elements-into-array-from-regex-group-that-ma

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanx a lot.but why are the two links appearing two times

Comment: array 0 - matched string. Array 1 -group 1. Array 2- group 2.

Comment: @AvinashRaj was `match_all` nacessary?`$1` `$2` cant they be used directly somehow?

Comment: replace the  last line with `print_r($matches[1]);\n
print_r($matches[2]);`